# Create custom query for search?

Tags: custom-field, query, search, meta-query

I have create search box using ajax.If i enter any value in search input box that this value search in post title or post meta data and get all data of this value in custom post type.also query check only post title and specific post meta data. Not check in Post content or any other field.

I have tried this query

```
$args = array(
    's' => $keyword,
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'store',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'postal_code',
            'value' => $keyword,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This issue has been handled before, please use the site search, you should get your answer in the returned search results ;-)

Comment: Thanks Pieter,

I have search about this issue but not much help.

Comment: Really? ;-) [Here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=search+by+custom+field) is a search with 249 results

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your result-set, what result you are getting in `$query` obj. another thing, there is no need to use `'relation' => 'OR',` in meta query array, have a try with this as well. And instead of `'numberposts'` use `'posts_per_page'` this will help. :) or you can remove the meta_query and make your $arg something like

`$args = array(
's' => $keyword,
'post_type'=> 'store',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_key' => 'postal_code',
'meta_value' => $keyword,
'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
);`

Comment: Thanks Hari For reply,

I have removed 'relation' => 'OR'  also i have used 'posts_per_page' but not help. 

About Result set, no post found

Comment: are you sure, your variable `$keyword` have some value, or you can use this way, remove the meta_query array...
`$args = array(
  's' => $keyword,
  'post_type'=> 'store',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'meta_key' => 'postal_code',
  'meta_value' => $keyword,
  'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
  );`

Comment: Your query working fine but only for title if $keyword is any postal code result give a null

Comment: Ohh.. your meta_key should be like `'meta_key' => '_postal_code'`, just make it sure with your database.. ;)